# C# & ASP.NET MVC : call a view with ajax call

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to call a view with an ajax call on my current view. The following is my Ajax call that calls a function of my controller.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("EditCertificateObservation", "Frühwarnsystem")',
    data: {
        serverName: '@Model[0].ServerName',
        name: event.data.name,
        thumbprint: event.data.thumbprint,
        expiringDateStr: event.data.expiringDate,
        isChecked: document.getElementById(store + event.data.index).checked,
        model: data,
    },
});
```

This code is my controller function that returns a view to load.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult EditCertificateObservation(string serverName, string name, string thumbprint, string expiringDateStr, bool isChecked, string model)
{
    var newModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Store>>(model);

    var cert = new Certificate(serverName, name, thumbprint, expiringDateStr);
    var server = new Server(serverName);
    server.FetchIdByServerName();

    if (isChecked)
    {
        cert.AddToObservation(server.Id);
    }
    else
    {
        cert.DeleteFromObservation();
    }

    return View("Index");
}
```

To know for you: I call the ajax call with a checkbox on my view, which is dynamically generated. If I debug the controller function get called and runs but the browser doesn't load the view I return.

If you need more information, just ask here.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What's the name of the view you want to open with your Ajax ? Index ?

Comment: The index VIew i am opening in my code snippet is just to test, actually there will be opened another view later but first i want to run this with the index view where i dont need any model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open a view with after Ajax request than you just have to wait for the response of your controller then you can use `success`, but you can also use `failure` or `error` depend on your need, so your Ajax will be like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("EditCertificateObservation", "Frühwarnsystem")',
    data: {
        serverName: '@Model[0].ServerName',
        name: event.data.name,
        thumbprint: event.data.thumbprint,

        expiringDateStr: event.data.expiringDate,
        isChecked: document.getElementById(store + event.data.index).checked,
        model: data,
    },
        success: function (response) { 
        alert(response.message); 
        window.location.href = "/Frühwarnsystem/Index";

        // or with some parameter
        window.location.href ="/Frühwarnsystem/Index?id=" + response.counter;

        // or if you prefer with helper ...
        window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Frühwarnsystem","Index")';
        
        },
        failure: function (response) { alert("failure"); },
        error: function (response) { alert("error"); }
});
```

And to be a little more useful, your controller can send a **Json response** with some parameter for example, as follow:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult EditCertificateObservation(string serverName, string name, string thumbprint, string expiringDateStr, bool isChecked, string model)
{
    var newModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Store>>(model);

    var cert = new Certificate(serverName, name, thumbprint, expiringDateStr);
    var server = new Server(serverName);
    server.FetchIdByServerName();

    if (isChecked)
    {
        cert.AddToObservation(server.Id);
    }
    else
    {
        cert.DeleteFromObservation();
    }
    // Do some condition here to send an answer ...
    string message = "";
    int counter = 0;
    var response = new { counter, message };
    return Json(response);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling an ajax POST HTTP request. It means you can download the result of the call and assign it into a javascript variable. This result will not be displayed in the browser as a page. Take a look at examples of `$.post` [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/jquery-ajax-post-method/).